# Check structure against another structure by value

Tags: data-structures, dynamic, abap

I have this piece of dynamic coding. Where I need to check if a structure of keys is in another structure. Without checking the value of each field (if possible).

Logically it should be something like this:

```
IF ls_keys IN ls_data_struc.
  "do stuff
ENDIF.
```

yes I know that coding snippet doesn't work, but I think that shows best what I am asking.

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF tys_keys,
        matnr TYPE matnr,
        vkorg TYPE vkorg,
       END OF tys_keys.

TYPES: BEGIN OF tys_data,
        matnr TYPE matnr,
        vkorg TYPE vkorg,
        mtpos TYPE mtpos,
       END OF tys_data.

DATA: ls_keys TYPE tys_keys,
      ls_data_struc TYPE tys_data.
```

Example that should work:

```
ls_keys-matnr = '009988776655443322'.
ls_keys-vkorg = '0001'.

ls_data_struc-matnr = '009988776655443322'.
ls_data_struc-vkorg = '0001'.
ls_data_struc-mtpos = 'ALEN'.

IF ls_keys IN ls_data_struc.
  "do something
ENDIF.
```

Example that shouldn't work:

```
ls_keys-matnr = '112233445566778899'.
ls_keys-vkorg = '3145'.

ls_data_struc-matnr = '009988776655443322'.
ls_data_struc-vkorg = '0001'.
ls_data_struc-mtpos = 'ALEN'.

IF ls_keys IN ls_data_struc.
  "do something
ENDIF.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To only compare the component values of both structures, the simplest solution is to use the constructor operator [**`CORRESPONDING`**](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenconstructor_expr_corresponding.htm):

```
IF ls_keys = CORRESPONDING tys_keys( ls_data_struc ).
  "do something
ENDIF.
```

Answer (score 0):

If the fields are actually laid out similar to the snippet in your question,

```
If ls_keys = ls_data_struc(22). 
  “Do something
Endif.
```

Should also work. It would probably also be faster than using the corresponding operator,  but will have more limited applicability.

Comment: That's a possible solution, but I think hardcoding the sum of the lengths of the fields is not very good for maintainability (and it doesn't work if the structure has non-character components or not in the same order). It's just better for performance ('Substring: 35256.00 < CORRESPONDING: 78607.00' in my system, based on 100.000 iterations).

Comment: I agree, for many cases your answer is better.  Hence the "more limited applicability" in my answer.  That being said, there are times when you want to eek out every ounce of performance, and frankly for tables that aren't likely to change the maintainability risk is fairly low.